# Checking length of a textbox and showing relevant error message if its 0

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a textbox and im trying to check if it has anything in, and if it doesnt i need to show a relevant error message but even when i have entered something in it, it continues to show the error message

Iv created a it here http://jsfiddle.net/Atkinson1988/SzuVQ/

```
var DiarisedReason = $("#txtDiarisedReason").val();
if (jQuery.trim(DiarisedReason).length < 0);
{
alert('Please Enter Diarised Notes');
return false;
}
​
```

Im not sure what im doing wrong?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you not use a RequiredFieldValidator? - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use RequiredFieldValidator in asp.net, as it provides easy way to validate the server side controls.

```
<asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" runat="server"/>
```

and for Required field validator

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator2"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
                    Display="Static"
                    ErrorMessage="*"
                    runat="server"/>
```

then check for `Page.IsValid` in the page load event to submit the form.

```
if(page.IsValid)
{
  //then do success
}
else
{
 //do failure
}
```

if you want javascript/jquery solution, then you can try like this

you can do with val() also. something like this . `!` will check for the value in the textbox value.

```
if(!$("#txtDiarisedReason").val())
 alert('you have to enter the Reason');
```

alternativiley, you can check for trimmed value also. by using [trim()](http://api.jquery.com/trim)

check demo : [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SzuVQ/9/)

Answer (score 1):

You've got a semicolon after your conditional statement. That's why the alert is showing, even though your conditional checks for length less than 0...

Also you don't really need jQuery to do the trimming... the following works just as well:

e.g... `if (DiarisedReason.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '').length == 0) {`

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason it has to use JQuery instead of a .Net required field validator?

http://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/required-field-validator/